# Babel - Recursively transpile JS files in a directory and overwrite in the same file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

I want to transpile JS files in a folder recursively and overwrite the same files with transpiled JS.

```
babel build/sample.js --out-file build/sample.js
```

Using the above command, I can transpile a single file.  How could I do this recursively over a folder?

*Edit:*

- I don't want to use Webpack.
- My Source code will be in a different folder 'A' (with js.php files). And I use a PHP build process to generate a build folder 'B' (with .js files).  I want to apply Babel on folder 'B' after generating the build folder.
- I can't afford the time to make changes on to run Babel before the PHP build process now.

Comment: Using bash?  `for x in directory/*.js ; do babel "$x" --out-file "$x" ; done`

Comment: you'll lose all the original code. IMHO you should send the output to a separate directory. if your goal is to make an NPM package out of it, you can specify which files to include and exclude, and keep both the pre-and-post-transpiled code.

Comment: What is the motivation for placing them in the same location? That seems like an immediate problem, irrespective of whether it is technically possible.

Comment: My Source code will be in a different folder 'A'. And I use a PHP build process to generate a build folder 'B'.  I want to apply Babel on folder 'B' after generating the build folder.  My bad, I didn't explain this clearly.